# INVALID_ARGUMENT: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,10] labels_size=[32,25]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying building very basic CNN model for architect style classification using TensorFlow, Keras on M1 Pro(Ventura, on conda virtual-environment)

And this is my code:

*Dataset directory structure

testdataset
_label1
-image1
-image2
_label2
-image3
-image4
...

- Data Pipeline building
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUJ6d.png)
- CNN Model Building
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40wlb.png)
- model.summary()
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D13jI.png)

*result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eqPj.png)

I'm actual noob for this ML area, so I'm in desperate needs for you masters' help.
I've checked if it caused by GPU recognition issue but it recognize my gpu appropriately.

I'd really appreciate for all of your guys effort for my problem and I'd really thankful for just pointing out the trouble point. Also huge love for the resolutions.
Thank you guys. Hope you had a great day so far :P)

I'm actual noob for this ML area, so I'm in desperate needs for you masters' help.
I've checked if it caused by GPU recognition issue but it recognize my gpu appropriately.

I'd really appreciate for all of your guys effort for my problem and I'd really thankful for just pointing out the trouble point. Also huge love for the resolutions.
Thank you guys. Hope you had a great day so far :P)

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh thank you. I've never thought it can mean something else. Sorry, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Please do not post the image of source code or data. It is hard to reproduce the problem with that. Sample source code with input data, which reproduces the problem, increases the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @Azhar Kahn Thank you, I missed that point. I'll change it into proper way as you told. Thank you Azhar!

Comment: @creamcastella, the error states that your data has 25 labels, but you have passed 10 units in the last(output) layer of the model. Please try changing it to 25 and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!